# locale when login ubuntu 12.04 desktop

Tags: locale, environment

I logged in to Ubuntu 12.04 desktop via ssh, the env variables of locale had been set are followed:
`env | grep LC`

```
LC_PAPER=zh_CN.UTF-8  
LC_ADDRESS=zh_CN.UTF-8  
LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8  
LC_NUMERIC=zh_CN.UTF-8  
LC_TELEPHONE=zh_CN.UTF-8  
LC_IDENTIFICATION=zh_CN.UTF-8  
LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8  
LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8  
LC_NAME=zh_CN.UTF-8
```

so my question is:

where set such env, and why LC_CTYPE and LC_MESSAGES NOT set?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is speculative in nature

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: I really don't understand what you mean by "speculative in nature". To me they are questions about how Ubuntu works.

Comment: I suppose your question seemed ambiguous, I could not tell if you were ashing how to set environmental variables and/or speculate why the developers choose to set some and not other variables.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: There is nothing about LC_* or LANG in file /etc/environment and there is only one line: LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 in /etc/default/locale. But when log in Ubuntu 12.04 desktop, I found LC_* but LC_MESSAGES, LC_CTYPE and LC_COLLATE were set zh_CN.UTF-8. So I confused with that! And Gunnar Hjalmarsson's answer help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use Language Support to set language and regional formats, the resulting environment variables are written to `~/.pam_environment`, as you already have found out. When you apply system-wide, the variables are written to `/etc/default/locale`.

The reason why `LC_MESSAGES`, `LC_CTYPE` and `LC_COLLATE` are not set explicitly is that `LANG` is set, and the locale name in `LANG` is inherited by those three `LC_*` variables. You can check that by running the `locale` command instead of `env | grep LC`.

Comment: Yes, locale command can list all LC_* variables; but why LC_MESSAGES, LC_CTYPE and LC_COLLATE are NOT set in ~/.pam_environment?

Comment: Didn't I cover that in my answer? Because LANG is set, and LC_MESSAGES, LC_CTYPE and LC_COLLATE inherit the LANG value, which is good since they should have the same value as LANG. In other words there is no need to set them explicitly in ~/.pam_environment.

Answer (score 0):

System wide environmental variables are set in `/etc/environment` and, for locales `/etc/default/locale`

> /etc/environment - This file is specifically meant for system-wide environment variable settings. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line. Specifically, this file stores the system-wide path settings.
>
> /etc/default/locale - This file is specifically meant for system-wide locale (LC_*) environment variable settings. It is not a script file, but rather consists of assignment expressions, one per line.

For additional information, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale

As to "why LC_CTYPE and LC_MESSAGES NOT set?", I could not find a discussion, I suggest you might have better luck filing a bug report, feature request, or perhaps IRC. That part of your question may be considered off topic and speculative.

Comment: in /etc/environment there are nothing about LC_* and only one line: LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 in /etc/default/locale

Comment: I found the such env variables defined in $HOME/.pam_environment.  thx very much!

Comment: OK, glad you got it sorted =)